# Callback when store.each() iteration finished

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Is there a way to get a callback if an iteration through a store finished? Unfortunately you can't pass a callback to store.each(), are there other ways?

I need to do a lot of calculation with the associated models of the models in my store, so I would like to add all these associated records to one array and work with them. I need a callback when the array is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's always the same :D shortly after you ask a question you find an answer :D
I solved it like this:

```
this.opponents = [];
var count = 0;
tournament.Games().each(function (op) {
    op.getOpponent(function (op) {
        count++;
        this.opponents.push(op);
        if(count==tournament.Games().getAllCount()){
            callback.call(scope);
        }
    }, this);
}, this);
```

works very well.